# Coordinate-Additive Metric

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $R$ be the real numbers. I want to consider metrics $d: R^n \times R^n \rightarrow R$ such that there are functions $h: R \rightarrow R$ and  $\delta: R \times R \rightarrow R$ with
$$ d(x,y) = h \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \delta(x_i,y_i) \right).$$

This applies, for example, to the Euclidean distance, or more generally, to the metric induced by the $p$-norm with
$$h(z) = z^{1/p}$$
and
$$\delta(a,b) = |a-b|^p$$
resulting in
$$d(x,y) = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i-y_i|^p \right)^{1/p}. $$

In particular, I need this sum structure over the coordinates $i$ to build the metric. My questions:

- Does there exist a name for this kind of metric?
- Are there important examples of metrics possessing this structure beyond the $p$-norm example? I mean, otherwise it would not make much sense to consider this generalization.